# Looking for proper way to manage UWP libraries

Tags: dll, uwp, repository

I am looking for a proper way to manage UWP libraries. I see that I can only build .dll files, and they would be built to a local directory. But I'm looking for something like what exists for nuget packages, that can be in a repository which I can access with my other projects. Does such a thing exist?

Comment: Are the UWP libraries you mentioned class libraries? Maybe you could try to create a NuGet package with them, then you can install it in other projects or for others to use it. For more information about how to create NuGet package, you can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/guides/create-uwp-packages-cs).

Comment: Yep, they are class libraries in addition to some user controls. It does appear that the only way to achieve this is by creating a nuspec file like that document describes, and generating a nuget file from that. I was hoping for something more automated, or a proper repository for managing .dll files.

Comment: Currently, it is recommended to create a NuGet package to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to set up your own nuget server that does exactly you want to achieve. See official documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/hosting-packages/overview).